# Azure AD : how to redirect to sign in page by code manually

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I followed this [official sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph) to integrate Azure AD authentication into my ASP.NET Core application. Everything is working well, and I can call the MS Graph API successfully.

The problem is that after I signed in, I kept the browser opening and then I shutdown my application (simulate the server crashed), then I run the application again, then refreshing the page, I got an exception as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I debugged the code, and I found that the request went into my controller (I had `[Authorize]` on my controller so it should redirect to sign in page when app found the request doesn't be authenticated) and the exception appeared when run

```
var me = await _graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

This means the app thinks the request is authenticated.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphClient;

    public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphClient, ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _graphClient = graphClient;
    }
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {
        var me = await _graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
        ViewBag.Myname = me.DisplayName;
        return View();
    }
}
```

The reason for why the app not redirected to sign in page is that the browser stored cookie, after removing the cookie manually, the exception wouldn't appear and app would redirect to sign in page.

I think I need a global filter to handle the exception, by removing the cookie (I'm not sure if it can remove the cookie) and then redirect to sign in page manually, but I failed to find any document to describe how to redirect to sign in page manually by code.

Any document or code sample is appreciated.

By the way, should we put effort on this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

•   As per my understanding on your query regarding the redirection to sign in page manually through code, I would suggest you to please go through the below code which suggests the same mechanism as you are expecting, i.e., **delete the cookie from browser memory for the session signed in and redirect to the sign in page again for login to a new session, but the below code is for ‘laravel’**: -

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $cookie = \Cookie::forget('first_time');

    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();


    return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/')- 
    >withCookie($cookie);
```

Also, you can use **‘\Cookie::queue(\Cookie::forget('first_time'));’** to avoid creating the cookie variable and redirecting with it.

Kindly find the link below for more details: -

***https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cookie-is-not-deleting-using-cookieforget-after-logout***

•   Similarly, I would suggest you follow the **cookie-based identity authentication method using the ASP .Net Core** sample code as below: -

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

 var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

 builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
 builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication
 (CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
 .AddCookie(options =>

   {
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Forbidden/";
   });

   builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

  var app = builder.Build();

  if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

app.Run();
```

For more information, kindly find the documentation link below which explains the cookie authentication configuration in detail: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your kind code, but what I most concerned is how to redirect to sign in page manually by code, this sign in page is provided by microsoft identity platform but not asp.net core cookie authentication.

Comment: I also had a discussion with some other top users of azure ad, and I got his point that azure ad had done all it can do, so we shouldn't pay much attention on this kind of issue, we may try to catch the exception and just kindly let users know to try to sign out and sign in again manually.